# Python webscraping problem : Local Storage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-webbrowser

I'm new to web scraping and it's pretty difficult

So i try to get data from a website where there are selectors (categories) which are not real button

My first idea was to modify the Local Storage, indeed when I change category, local storage variable also change

`print(driver.execute_script("localStorage.getItem('images_channels')"))` with Selenium but doesn't work

Any idea ?

Comment: I doubt changing the local storage would do much. Can you see the data when you load the page or do you need to click anything to get the data?

Comment: I must click on category selector but there is no button class, so i trying by pass through local Storage
https://imgur.com/a/oUAHGaX

Comment: The data sounds like it's being loaded dynamically using javascript. Try using your browser dev tools and look at the networking tab for XHR calls, then you can scrape that.

Comment: But the category selection doesn't "reset" when i'm refreshing ?

Comment: And yes! I see the result in XHR, but the problem is how to get it (correct page number, correct category)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yYCYDxP

Comment: I've something like that but i have just to request with this informations ?

Comment: Ok, so after trying severing times i wrote this https://imgur.com/a/5iFh2SW But i get an error �{"errors":["Not found."]} Do u know how can i fix this ?

Comment: Another update, i do get instead of post and response 200 with text "c " so it might be wrong how can i fix it ?